# Can anyone suggest one test management system working with Mingle

Tags: testing

Now I have used Mingle as my project management system(develop with story card and report bug when check those cards.) But, do we have any mingle like test management system? Which I need is to create test cases, assign test cases and execute of cause.
And if test cases can set the related to mingle story card, and with bugs that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

u can use PractiTest and synchronize the issue with their API.